# VS Code always prompts: "older version of PackageManagement known to cause issues"

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am using the current VS Code (1.53.2) on Win 10

Every time I run it, I get this message:

> You have an older version of PackageManagement known to  cause issues
> with the PowerShell extension.  Would you like to update
> PackageManagement  (You will need to restart the PowerShell extension
> after)?

I have done the update (which appears to run cleanly), restarted, all that, but this just keeps coming up.

How to resolve all the way?

Comment: Give the instructions on this page a try to update PackageManagement - https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2019/02/update-powershellget-and-packagemanagement/

Answer (score 2):

In my case only manual installing of latest stable PackageManagement and PowerShellGet modules from https://www.powershellgallery.com helped. See this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/scripting/gallery/how-to/working-with-packages/manual-download?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Here's the English version of the guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/how-to/working-with-packages/manual-download?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: I already had the latest PackageManagement. I completed the steps in the guide (install latest NuGet provider, ensure use of TSL 1.2, update PowerShellGet) and it updated PowerShellGet from 2.2 to 2.2.5. The message, "Old version of PackageManagement ...." went away. I just needed the latest version of PowerShellGet.

Answer (score 1):

After digging a lot, the problem set migrated to a more specific set of issues related to updates in the powershell package and package management sphere.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66305351/147637) describes the more specific problem, and has steps that led to the resolution.